# How can differentiate between dividable by 2 and dividable by 4?

Tags: java, php, c++, c

I would like to create a program that is :

for 1st item , do A, for 2nd item , do B, for 3rd item , do C , for 4th item, do D, for 5th item , do A, for 6th item , do B, for 7 th item do C , for 8th item , do D .... and so on. The pattern is like that .

And now , I can differentiate odd and even, but how can I achieve the above, this one seem not work

```
            if ( position % 2 == 0) {
                if ( position % 4 == 0) {
                    D();
                } else {
                    B();
                }
            } else {
                if ( position % 3 == 0) {
                    C();
                } else {
                    A();
                }
            }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Just `switch` on `position % 4`! There are only 4 possible results: 0, 1, 2 or 3

Comment: why jquery tag? did you mean javascript?

Comment: Use only the language tag that you are using, or if it doesn't matter, use [**language-agnostic**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
position % 3 == 0
```

should be

```
position % 4 == 3
```

to select the last of every four items. You'll also need to reorder the function calls to match your description; I think the correct order is A,C,D,B.

The code would be clearer using a switch:

```
switch (position % 4) {
    case 0: A(); break;
    case 1: B(); break;
    case 2: C(); break;
    case 3: D(); break;
}
```

assuming whichever language you're actually using supports such a construct.

Comment: This works for all the listed languages but jquery, because that makes no sense, jquery being a library, but works in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can try like follow

```
if(position%4==1)
{ 
 A();
}
if(position%4==2)
{ 
 B();
}
if(position%4==3)
{ 
 C();
}
if(position%4==0)
{ 
 D();
}
```

this is for just giving an idea. If you want to use `if-else`, `switch-case` methods, change as per your wish.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
switch (position % 4)
 {
case 0:
 A();
 break;
case 1:
 B();
 break;
case 2:
 C();
 break;
case 3:
 D(); 
break;
}
```